# Using BNF in DecimalFormat

Tags: java

Does anyone have experience using BNF in DecimalFormat?

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html

See under "Number Format Pattern Syntax"

As I wish to convert from double to string as follow :

```
0.10 ->      "0.1"
0.110 ->     "0.11"
0.11...10 -> "0.11...1"
```

Currently, I am using

```
 DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.#############################");
```

I just feel that it is not a very smart way. I wish to specific, "has 1 or more #"

Comment: Please edit this question to be more clear about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum number of digits to the right of the decimal point in double-precision arithmetic is 17, I believe, so just construct a DecimalFormat like `0.#################`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [Double.parseDouble()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)?

Comment: My input is in double, not string.

Comment: If your input is a double, then why do you need the DecimalFormat?

Comment: Because I need to convert them to string.

Comment: If your input is double, where do you get the trailing 0 from? Is not String.valueOf(double) doing what you want?

Comment: Using String.valueOf(double), for case 0 and 1.0, you will have trailing 0 in your string.

Comment: "what's wrong with the solution you have" --> so, what is the exact number of "#" I shall have?

Comment: There is no way to do the general solution you're hoping for using DecimalFormat. You just have to put 16 #s to permit any number of double-precision digits.